# Переключение между screen'ами в linux

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

Доброй ночи, имеется сервер на ubuntu (подключаюсь через PuTTy) и несколькими screen'ами с постоянно работающими bash скриптами, но при сочетании клавиш Ctrl + a w, я вижжу только 0*$ bash. Вопрос заключается вот в чем, как мне сделать, чтобы все эти сессии были "связаны" и я мог переключаться уже между ними, а не каждый раз - Ctrl + a d, screen -x ... ? При выводе скринов, после каждого написано (Detached).

Comment: Создавайте один-единственный screen и уже внутри него создавайте «вкладки» с помощью Ctrl+a c

Comment: @andreymal, большое спасибо, а можете написать в ответы, чтобы я поставил решение?

Comment: В этом нет необходимости. Иногда комментарий может являться ответом.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk все мы бываем ленивыми, но в идеале ответам не место в комментариях.